# Node red crashing when use http request to call a webservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I'm having a problem developing a node that makes web service calls.

I'm using:

- Node-RED version: **v0.17.5**
- Node.js  version: **v8.4.0**

It is throwing that exception

```
node-red_1     | 30 Aug 21:21:50 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
node-red_1     | 30 Aug 21:21:50 - TypeError: Cannot set property listening of #<Server> which has only a getter
node-red_1     |     at _clone (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/clone/clone.js:156:16)
node-red_1     |     at _clone (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/clone/clone.js:156:18)
node-red_1     |     at _clone (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/clone/clone.js:156:18)
node-red_1     |     at _clone (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/clone/clone.js:156:18)
node-red_1     |     at _clone (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/clone/clone.js:156:18)
node-red_1     |     at clone (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/clone/clone.js:196:10)
node-red_1     |     at Object.cloneMessage (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/util.js:53:13)
node-red_1     |     at /usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/flows/Flow.js:262:48
node-red_1     |     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
node-red_1     |     at Flow.handleError (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/flows/Flow.js:256:34)
```

I have a list of data that I need to POST to a webservice.
Everything works fine until I fire my HTTP post.
Basically, I have this snippet of code

```javascript
    const objects = msg.payload || []
    const hpptCalls = objects.map(obj => (callback) => {
        processObject(obj, callback)
    })
    async.parallelLimit(hpptCalls, 5, (err, results) => {
        node.send(msg)
    })
```

Inside my *processObject* function, I have almost the same code that exists in core node 21-httprequest.js

```javascript
    const req = http.request(options, res => {
        let data = ''
        res.on('data', chunk => {
            data += chunk
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
            callback(null)
        })
    })

    req.setTimeout(120000, () => {
        node.error('Error', msg)
        req.abort()
        callback('Error')
    })

    req.on('error', err => {
        node.error(err, msg)
        callback(err)
    })

    if (content) {
        req.write(JSON.stringify(content))
    }

    req.end()
```

But, it seems that when the first HTTP post is called, my node-red crash entirely with that exception. I can figure what is the problem. I put a lot o try catches thinking that my code is breaking something, but it is a straightforward code.

Comment: First view, part of the code try to clone a Server class which has read only attributes... Maybe you add some cyclic data?

Comment: The basic issue is the same as the one you added your comment to yesterday - https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/1367 - Your message has an uncloneable property on it. It's hard to see from your code here what property that may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently found the problem, as mentioned in project's github. At a random point in the flow, someone put a function node with the following code

```
return {
   "_msg": msg
   [other properties]
}
```

Thanks! (It was hard to find the problem lol, we have a big flow).